# Paging in ASP.NET gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, custompaging

I am looking for paging in which I can enter values in a box to reach at desired page something like this.

[image]

I googled it. but could not find this. Help me if you have links or code.
I am working on asp.net 4.0.
Thanks

Comment: Not sure about `ASP.Net GrridView` but telerik has handled paging very well in `RadGrid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out of the box functionality. To do that, you'd need to override the `DataBound` event of the gridview and add a custom pager row. [This CodeProject tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20870/A-very-nice-and-complete-custom-GridView-pager-wit) or [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25835/GridView-Custom-Paging-with-PageSize-Change-Dropdo) might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

As told by Echilon i used [CustomPager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32559/Paging-in-Grid-View-using-Slider-Extender) and used textbox instead of slider in it.